# Git clone project into manually-copied folder

Tags: git

I'm in the process of deploying a stage site to a production site. One of my coworkers decided to copy the files using FTP into the production server, however I am tracking the project using git, and I'd like to use the master branch for the production server, but I want to be careful with the files that could have changed.

I am thinking that this could be a safe approach:

```
cd production_dir
git init
git add . -A
git commit -m "Before merge"
git remote add origin git://repourl
git fetch origin
git merge -u origin/master
```

There's only one restriction: I don't have access to create folders on the ../ path, so I can't do, for example:

```
git clone git://repourl production_dir_git
cp -r production_dir/* production_dir_git/
rm production_dir && mv production_dir_git production_dir
```

This is a production ready site so I need to be extra careful. What's a good and safe approach?

Comment: "One of my coworkers decided to copy the files using FTP into the production server" --- just revoke their access from prod. Grant permissions back when they learn how to deal with SCMs

Comment: I don't have access to do that either, but well, there has to be a way to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that fetching your origin into initialized repo with one commit will break.

If you really have to handle this task, I would propose:

### copy `.git` from your repo into your production server directory

git has a beauty, that all lives in that directory. Immediately after this you shall be able doing `$ git status`.

If from your local repo and the production server you see share repo as the same url, you shall then play with fetch etc.

In case you did in your local repo something, what does not work on production server, you shall find it (and be able to fix it) by reviewing and editing files in root of `.git`.